# Como puedo meter una lista a un ciclo

Tags: java, array, lista

---

```
List lista=new ArrayList();
lista.add(xo);
for(lista.size()){ 
}
```

---

En el for me marca error pero no se de que manera trabajar con el tamaño que hay en la lista, en mi caso solo hay un dato que es "xo" así que solo daría una vuelta el for pero no funciona con el size() y no se de que otra manera lograr eso, probablemente este haciendo mal el for pero no tengo idea (este lenguaje no lo manejo). Lo que busco es comparar cada uno de los datos que hay en la lista con una variable independiente.

Comment: esa no es la forma de escribir un for.... revisaste la documentacion? tal vez querias hacer un for each?

Answer (score 1):

**Java For**

bucle basico en este caso tenemos una lista y la vamos a recorrer a través del método size que define el tope.

```
List<String> lista= new ArrayList<String>();
    lista.add("hola");
    lista.add("que");
    lista.add("tal");
    lista.add("estas");
    
    for (int i=0;i<lista.size();i++) {
      
      System.out.println(lista.get(i));
    }
```

**Java ForEach**

El uso de Java ForEach nos permite recorrer la lista de elementos de una forma mas compacta y el código se reduce.

```
for(String cadena :lista) {
      System.out.println(cadena);
    }
```

si vas a comparar dependera del tipo de dato que es `xo` si es de tipo cadena usa `equals` de ser tipo numerico usa `==`

[Fuente](https://www.arquitecturajava.com/java-foreach-y-sus-opciones/)

Answer (score 0):

te recomiendo primero usar ArrayList en lugar de List , es más moderno, usa la función forEach, que significa "para cada uno", tú le indicas que hacer y la función se encarga hacerlo con todos los nodos en lista. En tu caso seria; `lista.forEach((l) -> {//LO QUE QUIERES HACER});`

fuente: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arraylist-foreach-method-in-java/

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).